# Pass instanced property to second WPF window and then return property upon OK

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a second window which pops up when the user double-clicks a listview item in window 1.

I want to pass an instance of the listview item to the second window, which will be used to populate the data in the GUI. When the second window is closed it should return the new values from the GUI. Why does this not appear to work?

The error occurs in Doubleclick. It doesn't allow me to directly set the property **CurrentItem = selUser**. I get this error:

> *Error    1   'System.Windows.Window' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentItem' and no extension method 'CurrentItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Window' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\jmartini\Projects\wpf_listShowSelected\WpfApplication1_setup01\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs  34  24  WpfApplication1*

Furthermore i can't get the value in return by using **User val = editDialog.CurrentItem** when the dialog returns OK. I get the same error as the one mentioned above.

I'm not clear on how to fix this.

**WPF Window 1 (CS):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<User> items = new List<User>();
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com", Info = "A basketball player" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com", Info = "A soccer player" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com", Info = "A hockey player" });
            lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;
        }

        private void listViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem item = sender as ListViewItem;
            // create instance of original User to use for second window
            User selUser = item.Content as User;

            // POPUP WINDOW
            Window editDialog = new EditWindow();
            editDialog.Owner = this;
            editDialog.CurrentItem = selUser;
            editDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (editDialog.DialogResult.HasValue && editDialog.DialogResult.Value)
            {
                User val = editDialog.CurrentItem;
                Console.WriteLine("User pressed OK");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User pressed Cancel");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**WPF Window 2 (CS):**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class EditWindow : Window
    {
        public User CurrentItem {get; set;}

        public EditWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonOkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = true;
            Close();
        }

        private void ButtonCancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = false;
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the question to be clearer. What does 'It doesn't allow me to directly set the property' mean? Are you getting a compile error? Are you getting a runtime error? What are the errors / exceptions you are getting? 'It doesn't allow me to directly set the property' provides no useful information.

Comment: updated the question to include errors

Comment: Is this a compiler or runtime error?

Comment: Change to EditWindow editDialog = new EditWindow();

Comment: ^--- yeah... what he said... I'm so used to using `var` on the left side I didn't even notice you changed the type. :)

Comment: haha wow, i feel dumb for overlooking that one. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Change to EditWindow editDialog = new EditWindow();